# Assign Data to a User-Defined Table type from Select Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure which retrieves three columns from multiple tables. I want to get the results in a user defined multi-valued table and pass the variable to another procedure to perform operations on the variable data.

However it is not working. Any idea why it this not working?

```
--This is the initial stored procedure
Create Procedure spSelectData
AS
BEGIN
    Select 
        Userid, first_date, last_update
    From Users
END

--This is to create the table type.
Create type Task1TableType AS TABLE
(
     Userid nvarchar(20),
     First_date datetime,
     Last_update datetime
)

--Declare a table of type 
DECLARE @firstStep AS Task1TableType
(
    Userid nvarchar(20),
    First_date datetime,
    Last_update datetime
)

Insert @firstStep EXEC spSelectData

Select * from @firstStep

-- This is the procedure 1
CREATE PROC spTest1
   @TTType Task1TableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    Select * from @TTType
END
```

Comment: What doesn't work, are the errors?

Comment: Show your ` EXECUTE spTest1` statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is  here:

```
DECLARE @firstStep AS Task1TableType
(
    Userid nvarchar(20),
    First_date datetime,
    Last_update datetime
)


Insert @firstStep
EXEC spSelectData;
```

Should be:

```
DECLARE @firstStep AS Task1TableType;

Insert INTO @firstStep
EXEC spSelectData;

EXEC spTest1
  @firstStep;
```

There is no need to defining columns where type is defined, and `INSERT` require `INTO` clause. After that change your code works.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab1d7/4/0)**